# (Javascript) itertools.groupBy, e.g. [0,0,1,1,0] -> [[0,0],[1,1],[0]]

Tags: code-golf, javascript

(language-specific challenge)

### Specification:

Language: ECMAScript, any version<sup>[1]</sup>

Challenge: Somewhat like python's [itertools.groupBy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby): Your function `Array.group(f)` should take as input an "equivalence function" `f` whose output defines our notion of an "equivalence key" for array elements (like a sort key). The return value of `.group(f)` should be an array of arrays in the same order, split whenever the value of the keyfunc parameter changes (in the `===` sense).

```
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
    group: {
        value: function(f) {/*
            CODE GOES HERE
        */}
    }
});
```

### Examples / test cases:

```
> ['a','c','E','G','n'].group(x => x==x.toUpperCase())
[['a','c'], ['E','G'], ['n']]

> [1,1,'1'].group(x=>x)
[[1,1],['1']]

> [3,1,'1',10,5,5].group(x=>x+2)
[[3], [1], ['1'], [10], [5,5]]

> [{a:1,b:2,c:3}, {b:2,a:1,c:0}, {c:5}].group(x => JSON.stringify([x.a, x.b]))
[[{a:1,b:2,c:3},{b:2,a:1,c:0}], [{c:5}]]

> [].group(x=>x)
[]
```

### Scoring criteria:

score = # of characters that replace comment above (lower is better), with easements that:

1. whitespace and statement-separating semicolons don't count towards total<sup>[2]</sup>
2. variable names and keywords each count as exactly 1 characters towards total per use<sup>[3]</sup>; this includes builtins, so `Array.map.apply` would be 5 'characters' (however, builtins count their full length as tiebreakers)
3. -5 bonus points if `f` being undefined has same result as the identity function `x=>x`
4. you may modify the construct `function(f) {...}` for recursion/combinator purposes while keeping it as a `function` respecting rule #5, but must subtract from your score the extra characters incurred (i.e. imagine the scoring began earlier)

### Disallowances:

5. no side-effects which affect anything other than your code (such as modifying `this`, `window`, the prototype, etc.); as a corollary, all definitions must stay local to the `.group` function (e.g. `x=5` would be disallowed, but `var x=5` is fine)

minor notes:

<sup>[1] draft specs fine if in any major browser, proprietary extensions fine if in 2+ major browsers;

[2] as long as you don't try to compile a few megabytes-long whitespace ;-)

[3] as long as reflection is not used to abuse code-in-variable-names ;-)</sup>

---

### Errata:

Answer may do anything reasonable with regards to sparse arrays. e.g. `arr=[1,1]; arr[4]=1; arr` -> `[1, 1, empty × 2, 1]`. Possibilities include ignoring them (like `.map` and friends do), or treating them as `undefined` (like an incremental for-loop would), or anything reasonable. For example `arr.group(x=>x)` might return `[[1,1],[undefined,undefined],[1]]`, or `[[1,1,1]]`, or even more dubious things like `[[1,1],null,[1]]` if it makes sense. You may also assume sparse arrays do not exist.

edit: #2 now applies to keywords.

You may find the following snippet useful to estimate score (the rules supercede this snippet though):

```
var code = `......`;
console.log('score estimate:', code.replace(/\w+/g,'X').replace(/[\s;]/g,'').replace(/X(?=X)/g,'X ').length, '-5?');
```

Comment: Do you mean `Array.prototype.group` instead of `Array.group`?

Comment: Should one just submit the function body or a function (which should assigned to `Array#group` later) or the full shim including assignment? What if one want change the signature of the function? (e.g, function name, more (optional) parameters, default value for `f`)

Comment: Yes, I was writing it as shorthand for `Array.prototype.group`. You can change the signature of the function as long as it still conforms to the test cases; for example, adding the parameter `group(f,state) {` will incur a mere -2 penalty to score (since it is 2 'characters' longer, the comma and variable name). Submit whatever seems cleanest.

Comment: You had mentioned that the submission cannot pollute the globalThis (`window` in browser / `global` in node). Is pollute `this` valid through?

Comment: No, it is invalid to pollute `this`. Thanks for checking. I should clarify; I will edit the wording of rule #5 since no one has answered this yet.

Comment: Is `group()` operate in-place and return `this`, or return an new array without modifing `this`?

Comment: @tsh: returns a new array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84429/discussion-between-tsh-and-ninjagecko).

Comment: So as to possibly avoid the need for such clarifications, I'm suggesting using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/41024) next time! :-)

Comment: Why does `x => x==x.toUpperCase()` result in `[['a','c']..]` though `x=>x+2` results in `[[3], [1]..]`?

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 47 points (53 tiebreaker)

```
Array.prototype.group = function(f){
    const r = []
    let k = r
    for(const i of this)
        k !== (k = f ? f(i) : i) ? r.push(a = [i]) : a.push(i)
    return r
}
```

- Body: `+52`
- Identity comparison: `-5`
- Full-length built-ins: `+6`

#### Try it:

```js
Array.prototype.group = function(f){
    const r = []
    const k = r
    for(const i of this)
        k!==(k=f?f(i):i)?r.push(a=[i]):a.push(i)
    return r
}

console.log(
    ['a','c','E','G','n'].group(x => x==x.toUpperCase()),
    [1,1,'1'].group(x=>x),
    [3,1,'1',10,5,5].group(x=>x+2),
    [{a:1,b:2,c:3}, {b:2,a:1,c:0}, {c:5}].group(x => JSON.stringify([x.a, x.b])),
    [].group(x=>x)
)
```

---

## JavaScript, 48 points (56 tiebreaker)

More traditional code golf-y solution.

```
Array.prototype.group = function(f,r=[],k=r){
    this.map(i=>k!==(k=f?f(i):i)?r.push(a=[i]):a.push(i))
    return r
}
```

- Signature: `+9`
- Body: `+44`
- Identity comparison: `-5`
- Full-length built-ins: `+8`

#### Try it:

```js
Array.prototype.group = function(f,r=[],k=r){
    this.map(i=>k!==(k=f?f(i):i)?r.push(a=[i]):a.push(i))
    return r
}

console.log(
    ['a','c','E','G','n'].group(x => x==x.toUpperCase()),
    [1,1,'1'].group(x=>x),
    [3,1,'1',10,5,5].group(x=>x+2),
    [{a:1,b:2,c:3}, {b:2,a:1,c:0}, {c:5}].group(x => JSON.stringify([x.a, x.b])),
    [].group(x=>x)
)
```

Comment: Hopefully I got the scoring right. :P

Comment: A `const` variable declaration `const k = r` cannot be changed `k=f`, the value of a variable declared using `let` can be changed

Comment: full-length built-ins?

Comment: @guest271314 Fixed, thank you!

Comment: @ninjagecko Per your scoring criteria #2: "builtins count their full length as tiebreakers."

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 90 bytes, 82 points

```javascript
return((o,p,O)=>this.map(v=>(O=o,(o=f?f(v):v)===O?p.push(v):p=[v])))(0/0).filter(x=>x.pop)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVLNa9swFL/nr3g3S0xV7IZcHJQyxhj0UA9GezE@yK6cqvMsIcnGIfhvz6Q4SRuz2wRP6Ov38Z7eO@@5rYzU7q5Vr@JYqdY62DWq5M0LN5KXjbDA4PFX9kStM7LdyXqPsvJdVI7@FnuL6q6tnFQtIAwHMMJ1pgX3Ju0GRoQx3iwW5@evopat@GmUFsZJYdFXY/ieaqOccnstCBwW4MfOqE6n500YPW86kcJFCdVe6TgpIaSIJhlm2yBJ/3CNerZFGVMEKVY/1KjHaY8ZY9mDprqzb@FAs7wvvDcUL2NMa9k4YdDAtgPVSuPjRXdcTPMYkgilUY2gjdqhPOIRiSof33388NFGBT35RgOwLQyMDdSpZ@1T/catmAqxXEJ@gRYE8jP6tPQExUwkIQmJkg9i7@/K4u8KkofbOWo1oUgSkzVZfwZ/ub/CV0EzOQknJ/0kDnMAzPkOPE1Imd6TKl2N/ovCMhxVaRy2Vboeb1KftUo@UE5goGXxUYJbyhvG4GLinPv4Vxlmb/6jS8F3yLzv8eb4Fw)

> 90 - 3 (`this` counts as 1 bytes) - 5 (default `f` as `x=>x`) = 82 points

Comment: I love the use of `NaN!==NaN`

Comment: Your latest edit seems to have broken the test cases.

Comment: Using NaN rather than 0/0 to have lower score?